# Suitable technology, framework, language for web-project

Tags: web-applications

I have a private "consumer-like" web-project on my mind that should have a nice design (most likely third party template), potentially a CMS environment to author static content (e.g. typo3) and foremost a fancy web application embedded in certain parts of the page.

Now coming more from the Enterprise-SW world - mostly backend and as mentioned above some application like web-interfaces I'm struggling getting hold on what technology to use for these class of web projects?

Java & Co (GWT, Vaadin, etc.) seem to be an overkill and more suitable for web-based applications. I'm not sure how well it integrates with common CMS solutions such as Typo3 & Co. as well.

Going directly to PHP or Rails on the other hand seems to be just enough to show some dynamic content and building a little more complex applications could turn out to be an issue. That said being inexperienced with PHP or Ruby.

Apache vs. Tomcat is also an issue if I want to host the end-result at low costs.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Choosing a web framework highly depends on your specific needs. You better try with a "proof of concept" using each framework you think will work.

About the hosting costs... Java hosting is more expensive than PHP. Not sure about Ruby.